# Assign the second value of an array of string to a string variable in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have an array of string declared as

```
Dim name as String()
```

and a string declared as

```
Dim lastname as string
```

and the result of the split performed is assigned to this array

```
name = line.Split(New String() {"[ seperate      ]"}, StringSplitOptions.None)
```

and I am assigning the second value of the name array to the string lastname

```
lastname = name(0)
```

But no value is assigned to lastname eventhough the splitting is happening

any suggestion will be really helpful

Comment: It might be a good idea to spell "separate" correctly if that is part of the actual data.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to assign the **second** value of the array this is incorrect:

```
lastname = name(0)
```

Then you want this instead:

```
lastname = name(1)
```

But if the result for the first  is already an empty string that won't work either. So your split seems not to be correct. Maybe you don't want to split by the whole word including the spaces but:

```
line.Split(New String() {"[seperate]"}, StringSplitOptions.None)
```